# How to distinguish escaped characters from non-escaped e.g. "\x27" from "x27" in a string in Common Lisp?

Tags: string, hex, escaping, common-lisp

Solving [Advent of Code 2015 task 8 part2](https://adventofcode.com/2015/day/8#part2)  I encountered the problem to have to distinguish in a string the occurrence of "\x27" from plain "x27".
But I don't see a way how I can do it. Because

```
(length "\x27") ;; is 3
(length "x27")  ;; is also 3
(subseq "\x27" 0 1) ;; is "x"
(subseq "x27" 0 1)  ;; is "x"
```

Neither `print`, `prin1`, `princ` made a difference.

```
# nor does `coerce`
(coerce "\x27" 'list)
;; (#\x #\2 #\7)
```

So how then to distinguish in a string when "\x27" or any of such
hexadecimal representation occurs?

- It turned out, one doesn't need to solve this to solve the task. However, now I still would like to know whether there is a way to distinguish "\x" from "x" in common lisp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string literal `"\x27"` is read as the same as `"x27"`, because `\` is an escape character in string literals.  If you want a string with the contents `\x27`, you need to write the literal as `"\\x27"` (i. e. escape the escape character).  This has nothing to do with the strings themselves.  If you read a string from a file containing `\x27` (e. g. with `read-line`), then the four-character string `\x27` results.

Comment: Thank you! This caused me some brain quirks ... :D

Answer (score 1):

By the time that the Lisp reader gets to work, `\x` is the same as `x`. There may be some way to turn this off - I wouldn't be surprised - but the original text talks about Santa's file.

So, I created my own file, like this:

```
x27
\x27
```

And I read the data into special variables like this:

```
 (defun read-line-crlf (stream)
    (string-right-trim '(#\Return) (read-line stream nil)))

 (defun read-lines (filename)
    (with-open-file (stream filename)
      (setf x (read-line-crlf stream))
      (setf x-esc (read-line-crlf stream))
    ))
```

The length of `x` is then 3, and the length of `x-esc` is 4. The returned string must be trimmed on Windows, or an external format declared, because otherwise SBCL will leave half of the CR-LF on the end of the read strings.